# Talend: How to remove a specific XML tag from output when the source file is a .txt file instead of xml

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

In Talend, I am supposed to remove a particular XML tag from the output when it has a blank value. But the issue is that the source is a .txt file so i am not using an XML tree in the input to work on tags individually.

Design is: `tFileInputDelimited` as the input component (then `tMap` for transformation) and then `tAdvancedXMLOutput` for generating the xml.

I can’t find the option to remove that specific tag anywhere.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

I tried removing it in `tMap` but it removes the whole tag from the xml even when it doesn’t have a blank value. Or it creates a blank tag if I use the same in if-else